# Errors when trying to solve large system of PDEs

Tags: python-3.x, integration, pde, fipy

I have a system of 18 linear (i'm assuming) PDEs. Howe ever they are very awkwardly shaped PDEs. Every time I try to use FiPy to solve the system of coupled PDEs I get an error. I have fixed most of them on my own but I can't seem to get past this one.

First you will need a list of equations that will be added later in the program:

```
import time
from fipy import Variable, FaceVariable, CellVariable, Grid1D, Grid2D, ExplicitDiffusionTerm, TransientTerm, DiffusionTerm, Viewer,PowerLawConvectionTerm, ImplicitSourceTerm
from fipy.tools import numerix
import math
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
Temperature = 500.0 #Temperature in Celsius

Temp_K = Temperature + 273.15 #Temperature in Kelvin

Ea = [342,7,42,45,34] #Activation energy in order from the list excel/word file
#Frequency factor ko (Initial k)
k_0 =[5.9 * (10**15), 1.3 * (10**13), 1.0 * (10**12), 5.0 * (10**11), 1.2 * (10**13)]
fk1 = [math.exp((-1.0 * x)/(R*Temp_K)) for x in Ea] #Determines k value at given temperature value (exp(-Ea/R*T))
final_k = [fk1*k_0 for fk1,k_0 in zip(fk1,k_0)] #Multiplys by the inital k value to determine the k value at the given temperature (ko * exp(-Ea/R*T))
     final_kcm = [x for x in final_k]
def rhs(eq):
       eq_list = [-1.0*final_kcm[0]*EDC - final_kcm[1]*EDC*R1 - final_kcm[2]*EDC*R2 - final_kcm[3]*EDC*R4 - final_kcm[4]*EDC*R5 - final_kcm[5]*EDC*R6,
       final_kcm[2]*EDC*R2 - final_kcm[8]*EC*R1 + final_kcm[13]*VCM*R2,
       final_kcm[1]*EDC*R1 + final_kcm[6]*R2*R1 + final_kcm[7]*R1*R3 + final_kcm[8]*R1*EC + final_kcm[9]*R1*C11 + final_kcm[10]*R1*C112 +  final_kcm[12]*R1*VCM + 2.0*final_kcm[20]*R1*C2H2,
       2.0*final_kcm[20]*R2*C2H2,
       final_kcm[15]*R5*VCM,

       return eq_list[eq]
```

Here is the rest of the program I use to generate the system of PDEs.

```
EDC = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, hasOld=True, value=10)
EC = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, hasOld=True, value=0)
HCl = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, hasOld=True, value=0)
Coke = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, hasOld=True, value=0)
CP = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, hasOld=True, value=0)

EDC.constrain(10, mesh.facesLeft)
EC.constrain(0., mesh.facesLeft)
HCl.constrain(0., mesh.facesLeft)
Coke.constrain(0., mesh.facesLeft)
CP.constrain(0., mesh.facesLeft)

nsp =18
u_x = [[ [0,]*nsp for n in range(nsp) ]]
for z in range(nsp):
    u_x[0][z][z] = 1.0

eq0 = TransientTerm(var = EDC) == PowerLawConvectionTerm(coeff = u_x, var = EDC) + ImplicitSourceTerm(rhs(0),var = EDC)
eq1 = TransientTerm(var = EC) == PowerLawConvectionTerm(coeff = u_x, var = EC) + ImplicitSourceTerm(rhs(1),var = (EC))
eq2 = TransientTerm(var = HCl) == PowerLawConvectionTerm(coeff = u_x, var = HCl) + ImplicitSourceTerm(rhs(2),var = (HCl))
eq3 = TransientTerm(var = Coke) == PowerLawConvectionTerm(coeff = u_x, var = Coke) + ImplicitSourceTerm(rhs(3),var = (Coke))
eq4 = TransientTerm(var = CP) == PowerLawConvectionTerm(coeff = u_x, var = CP) + ImplicitSourceTerm(rhs(4),var = (CP))


eqn = eq0 & eq1 & eq2 & eq3 & eq4 

if __name__ == '__main__':
     viewer = Viewer(vars = (EDC,EC,HCl,Coke,CP))
     viewer.plot()

for t in range(1):
    EDC.updateOld()
    EC.updateOld()
    HCl.updateOld()
    Coke.updateOld()
    CP.updateOld()

    eqn.solve(dt=1.e-3)
```

Sorry for the long code but I can't really show it any other way. Anyway this is the error it returns :

> File
>   "C:\Users\tjcze\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fipy\matrices\scipyMatrix.py",
>   line 218, in addAt
>       assert(len(id1) == len(id2) == len(vector))
>
> AssertionError

What should I do to get this system to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of whatever you're trying to do with `u_x`.  `u_x` should be a rank-1 `FaceVariable`. 
Its shape should be #dims x #faces (or #dims x 1); it should not be (#eqns x #eqns).

Setting `u_x = [1.]` gets rid of the `AssertionError`.

You will then get a series of warnings:

```
UserWarning: sweep() or solve() are likely to produce erroneous results when `var` does not contain floats.
```

Fix this by initializing all of your `CellVariables` with floats, e.g.,

```
EDC = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, hasOld=True, value=10.)
```

instead of

```
EDC = CellVariable(mesh=mesh, hasOld=True, value=10)
```

With those changes, the code runs. It doesn't do anything interesting, but that's hardly surprising, as it's *way* too complicated at this stage. 18 equations only obfuscates things. I *strongly* recommend you troubleshoot this problem with <= 2 equations.

At this point, your equations aren't coupled at all (`eq0` only implicitly depends on `EDC`, `eq1` only on `EC`, etc.). This isn't wrong, but not terribly useful. Certainly no point in the `eq = eq0 & eq1 & ...` syntax.  EDC is the only variable with a chance of evolving, and it's constant, so it won't evolve, either.

In future, please provide examples that actually run (up to the point of the error, anyway).

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help! Trust me when I tried to make this as useful of a question as I could but I'm still getting familiar with FiPy. It seems extremely useful but i'm still in the process of learning its methodology and syntax. I previously designed a program that solves the equations in the first block as a system of linear ODEs, and it works exactly as it should. Now i am trying to add in a linear spacial dimension (dCi/dx) but i'm not quite sure how to do this. Am I using  FiPy correctly to achieve this? (I promise you I have read the documentation as thoroughly as I can)

Comment: I'd need to see the math you're trying to represent to know whether you're approaching it the right way. Two or three equations until you're sure you have things working correctly. You'll definitely want to look for ways to couple your equations together; this will happen in your `ImplicitSourceTerms`, e.g., in `eq4`, instead of having `ImplicitSourceTerms(coeff=final_kcm[15]*R5*VCM, var=CP)`, you'd be better off with `ImplicitSourceTerms(coeff=final_kcm[15]*R5*CP, var=VCM)`.

Comment: This saved me, as well! Is there any point in allowing `int` Cell/Face variables at all?

Comment: Yes, there are internal cases where FiPy stores `int` in `MeshVariables`.